# FancyBox - How to close mp4 video on end

Tags: jquery, fancybox

am using FancyBox for mp4 videos and wish to close the box on end of video

I have looked through FancyBox documentation but could not find anything concrete.
I see there are a few threads for youtube videos, however my videos are all local

Any ideas on the code required to close a local mp4 video after the video has been played using FancyBox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the fancybox part, but maybe try something like this:

```
$('video').on('ended',function(){
    $.fancybox.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `afterShow` callback to bind 'ended' event:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  afterShow: function(current, slide) {
    slide.$slide.find("video").on("ended", function() {
      $.fancybox.close();
    });
  }
});
```